# How can I make a UIView that is stretchable by its corners?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'd like to have a UIView where the user can select each of the four corners and stretch the view by independently moving them.

How would I implement such a view?

Comment: Do you mean there are points drawn in the corners and the user can drag them to change the size of the view?

Comment: k4k could you explain you  question again. I don't think is clear ;)

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will need to subclass UIView and handle touch events manually.  When you get a touch event, you will have to do some math and then set the frame of the view to the new size.  I'd recommend making the background image a stretchable image using stretchableImageWithLeftCap:topCap.  It shouldn't actually be that hard.